# Package not found error even its there

Tags: java

[C:\tomcat\webapps\Beer-v1\WEB-INF\classes\com\example\model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itrRf.jpg)

I have `BeerExpert.class` under `com.example.model` and `BeerSelect.java` under `com.example.web` i had imported `BeerExpert.class` in `BeerSelect.java` by

```
import com.example.model.*;
```

and tried to compile `BeerSelect.java` which result package not found error. Please help.

Comment: Please provide some more information. Where exactly is your class file stored (the path) and where is the source file you want to compile (path as well)? How are you trying to compile the code (javac, maven, etc)?

Comment: Can you give more information? Usually the IDE isn't relevant, but what IDE are you using?

Comment: @clabe45 iam using notepad.

Comment: Alright, I think that would explain it. I would suggest using an IDE such as Eclipse or NetBeans (google them).

Comment: Any reason you aren't using an IDE? It'll put all your class files into the correct places

Comment: i just attached an image to the post, which tells my path of the class file which i'm trying to import

Comment: @FlorianCramer iam just trying to compile the file at the same place of the source file.

Comment: From which path are you invoking `javac`? Should be from `C:\tomcat\webapps\Beer-v1\WEB-INF\classes`

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the compiler while you're in the "root"-directory of your packages. I assume you're trying to compile `BeerSelect.java` in the directory where the java-file resides. The compiler searches for packages below that which obviously will fail.